# Potential outside long rectangular conductor

Tags: electrostatics, potential, conductors

So I have a long conductor with a rectangular cross section (sides a and 2a). All sides have zero potential and one of the small ones has a constant potential $V_{0}$. Finding the potential inside is easy you just use separation of variables. But I have two problems:

1)How do i find the potential outside or to phrase it better my only thought was approximating the conductor as a long line and I can find it's charge distribution from my inside solution, but is there a way to find it without approximating ?

2)I find that the corners are a major problem in finding the outside solution as there is a discontinuity in the potential. Is that a true concern or am I completely wrong ?